# Questions regarding the text I'm presently reviewing

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have two questions about the same text. My first question is about the following sentence:

> The most substantial **planned change** is a **proposal** to alter what is
>   currently a temporary exhibition space and develop it into a permanent
>   exhibiting area.

Doesn't the word "proposal" here feel redundant? It seems like a too quick succession of synonyms to me.

---

My second question is in what sense does "would" add to the following sentence? Couldn't the author replace "would" with "will" here?

> The suggested alteration **would** create one complete open space for
>   permanent exhibitions. Further to this, there are plans to upgrade the lobby
>   so that the gallery **would** include an education facility with an adjacent
>   storage and plant room.

The text is about the existing and proposed layout of an art gallery.

Comment: Even though the two excerpts are from the same piece of writing, it's better to ask about them in two separate questions, IMHO.

Comment: yeah you right but I didn't want to waste time asking 2 related questions under different titles.. plus, they'd have a more base about the questions to answer.

Comment: Asking two questions under different titles will help other learners if they have the same question and are looking for the answer. I'm voting to close the question as too broad because I think this should be two separate questions.

Comment: @LMS  Yes, I agree.  If the questions were directly related it would be fine to group them but these are not related issues.  Cavid could you please edit this question to remove your second part, and post that as a separate question?

Comment: @Andrew then what will happen to the Mark Ripley's  answer  which I found awesome in all respects?

Comment: @CavidHummatov  I believe all the answers and questions stay but if your question is closed it won't be visible to others looking for something similar.  I'm not a moderator here so my comment was just a suggestion, maybe for the future?

Comment: I appreciate that @Andrew , but I think I've done nothing out of rules, these are not two irrelevant questions posted in the same section. I'm sure if I posted it seperately(especially second question), guys who'd answer woud've ask for more context to say anything exact about that, so I actually did all in one, easy for the community to look over. I think they will understand it.

Comment: @CavidHummatov  I think you misunderstood the request.  It's asked that you separate these questions into different posts, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

1) The word 'proposal' implies that the 'planned change' is not 'set in stone' (idiom). In other words, even though there is a planned change, it is open to being altered by further proposals, suggestions, or other improvements to the current plan. Not using 'proposal' would imply that the planning process for the 'planned change' has already been finalized or completed.

2) Replacing 'would' with 'will' in your second example text would be grammatically correct, but the replacement would change the meaning of the text slightly. This is because 'would' is more conditional than 'will'. Using 'will' implies that if one thing is done, something else **will** happen, while 'would' only suggests that the end result **may** or **will probably** happen.

Comment: Thanks for the rational comprehensive explanation. You did nicely compare the situations from both aspects .